# How to run .sln files on centos 7

Tags: centos7, sln-file

Now i have search for several days how to manage to run SLN files on centos7.

I haven't still figure it out.

This is my last change to figure it out, so now i hope someone can help me.

I really want this to work.

UPPDATE:

I have manage to install visual studio code, when i run its open crome to adress: localhost:8080

I only get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, `.sln` file is for `Visual Studio 20xx` such as 2019, 2017, 2015, and so on. `Visual Studio 20xx` is a kind of IDE including compiler on MS Windows.
As I know it cannot work on CentOS 7 without VM solutions such as VirtualBox.

But `Visual Studio Code` is a kind of IDE without compiler. It is normally used as a source code editor.
And it can run on Windows and CentOS 7.

If you have the project which including `.sln` file, I guess it should be managed on Windows 10.